# JackBe Mashups w/ PerformancePoint in MOSS

Tags: performancepoint, olap

Has anyone used JackBe mashups in a SharePoint environment hitting OLAP cubes with PerformancePoint 2007?  Any gotchas?

We're evaluating adding JackBe to our enterprise toolkit and they're soliciting technical recommendations...

Comment: please retag to `jackbe mashups performancepoint-2007` - I can't create tags.